# Google Sheets - Query another sheet (Array, Transpose)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to return the 'Standard' (columns C4:AG4) and 'Name' (A) of those that have a 'No' in either the 'Pre' or 'Post' for each Standard (see: columns C4:AG4 on the 3-5h example).

The list of names are displayed on (A4:A28).

, image: 3-5th example. I have attempted to Transpose (from Horiz to Vert) the 'Standard' values in an Index Sheet, but I'm having trouble associated the 'Standard' for each student.
For example, each student completes all 10 of the Multiple choice questions and either receives a Yes (Correct) or No (Wrong) answer.

I have provided an image example of what I'm expecting.

```
=UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY('3-5th Data Entry Example'!C4:AQ4)))


Desired Output:

If Student has a 'No' in either the Pre or Post (from sheet: '3-5th Data Entry sheet', their name(s) are returned

Standard 1    Student Name 1
Standard 2    Student Name 2    
Standard 3    Student Name 3
Standard 4    Student Name 4 
Standard 5    Student Name 5
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

[Dummy Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VlK07K9wp2tYOlZGR4Ow32O9FLkmSeFI7JYjVe-PfpM/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sure one moment

Comment: Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet with the desired output? You are more likely to get help if you provide these rather than screenshots which will take time to replicate what you have

Comment: Here is the Dummy Spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VlK07K9wp2tYOlZGR4Ow32O9FLkmSeFI7JYjVe-PfpM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: With your current spreadsheet format, this is the simple formula: `=QUERY('3-5th Data Entry Example'!A4:D,"Select A where C = 'No' or D = 'No'")`. You need to manually adjust the C and D for every column of the standard.

Comment: Thanks although I was attempting to have the following desired output Desired Output:

If Student has a 'No' in either the Pre or Post (from sheet: '3-5th Data Entry sheet', the following is returned:

3-PS2-4       Student Name 1
3-PS2-2       Student Name 2
1-LS3-1       Student Name 1
1-LS3-1       Student Name 4
1-LS3-1       Student Name 2

Comment: Returning the Standard and the Name for those that meet the criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Here's [one approach](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VlK07K9wp2tYOlZGR4Ow32O9FLkmSeFI7JYjVe-PfpM/edit#gid=1303047363&range=O2) you may test out:*

```js
=index(split(tocol(if('3-5th Data Entry Example'!C8:V="No",scan(,'3-5th Data Entry Example'!C4:V4,lambda(a,c,if(c="",a,c)))&"|"&'3-5th Data Entry Example'!A8:A,),1,1),"|"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you very much, this was very helpful! The query did return all of the No's as anticipated.